# Delete documents in a document library with pnp-js-core

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, office-365, pnp, pnp-js-core

How can I delete a document in a document library with Pnp-Js-Core, but I need the registry to be stored in the recycle bin.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `recycle` method of pnp-js.

Try and modify the below code. It will send the document to recycle bin and gives you the guid of the recycle bin item.

```
$pnp.sp.web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/testdev/Documents/presentation.pptx").
recycle().then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```